# deploynig different ear files in different clusters of same weblogic server domain

Tags: deployment, ear, weblogic12c

Hi I am new to this forum as well as weblogic server.My requirement is that I have an application that runs on a cluster having an admin server and three managed server MS1,MS2,MS3.Currently my application has two parts(or logic), both of which are in a single ear file.The part1 always occupies one server, say MS1 and rest in other two MS2 & MS3 .I want to divide my code in two different ear part1 and part2 with par1_ear deployed in MS1 and part2_ear deployed in MS2 and MS3 all running under same admin server

ear1 deployed in ----->MS1

ear2 deployed in ----->MS2 &MS3
All running under same managed server.

Can this be done if not other suggestion also welcome but i can have only one admin server and 3 clusters

Comment: Show your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you deploy your .ear files you can target specific machines in a cluster. Your deployments don't have to go to all machines in a cluster.

Also, if you really only want one server in the cluster to handle some specific event you might want to look into Singleton Services.

Have you had experience deploying applications in Weblogic before?

Comment: As I said new to weblogic server for the first time I am using it.But any ways thanks a lot this will help improve my application a lot with different ears running on different servers of different capacities